# Problem with the output of an exponential calculation

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to calculate an exponential calculation, I tried both ways, writing it with the normal `**` operator and the `pow()` function.

If I directly use numbers, everything works completely fine. But as soon as I use variables which get their value from input() functions the result is rounded, although I use the float argument.

I am quite new to coding, so please don't go to hard on me.

Code below:

```
pow(1.05,5), everything fine, result is 1.2762815625 and so on
float(pow(int(a),int(b)) the result is just 1.0, although it should be the same as above.
```

Answer (score 2):

it is because you are doing the power operation on int i.e first you are converting the `1.05` to `1` by doing `int(1.05)` and then calculating the `power()`. you need to apply `pow()` on `float()`

```
print(float(pow(float(1.05),float(5))))
```

or either

```
print(pow(float(1.05),float(5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the float function returns 1.0 is because of how it deals with integers.

For example:

```py
integer = 5.5236734
print(float(integer))
```

The above code's output will be:

```py
5.5236734
```

Now lets say you make some changes:

```py
integer = 5.5236734
print(int(integer))
```

First, we made `integer` a decimal number, and then we said to print the `int()` form of the decimal.

This will be the result:

```py
5
```

So, to fix your code, you just need to do this:

```py
a = 1.05
b = 5
print(float(pow(a, b)))
```

Which will output:

```py
1.2762815625000004
```

Hope this helps!